# Excel - Color rows with same value but the value of the cell is dynamic

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have an excel with over 10,000 rows with information that represent the following

| Object ID | Object Value | Object Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | ABC |
| 1 | B | ABCD |
| 1 | C | XYZ |
| 2 | D | QWERT |
| 2 | E | ASDF |
| 3 | R | ZXCV |

This goes on for ~10,000 values where it is 1:many mapping between Object ID and value/description. There are a total of ~6,000 unique Object values. My goal is to highlight all the unique object values and associated rows in a specific color. E.g. All rows with object value 1 can be red, all rows with object value 2 can be blue, and so forth. Is that something that is possible?

Edit: instead of each row having a unique color, I want to instead have alternating rows with the same color. Value 1 is red, value 2 is blue, value 3 is red, value 4 is blue.

Thank you.

Comment: It's possible, but it's not going to help you.  You're not going to derive any informational value out of colors that are as close together as 6000 colors are going to have to be.  There's only so many shades of red, for instance, that the human eye can discriminate, especially if they're not sitting right next to each other.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. What about alternating color. E.g. Value 1 is red, value 2 is blue, value 3 is red, value 4 is blue. This way, the people who are consuming the data can differentiate as they move from one row to the other.

Comment: Then if value 4 goes after value 2, both will be blue

Comment: I could sort it in a way, the value IDs are actually very large something like 2389534, and are in incremental order.

Comment: Your headers are misleading. Your Object values are A, B, C, D, not numerical. If you mean Object ID "values", then sort it so non unique ID's are near, select A2:A10000, set rule =A2=A1 so it will color repeated ID's

Comment: I am trying this on excel mac and it does not work. Is there a way to solve for this in excel mac?